# Jest - checking local storage is called in an async function that is being mocked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have an api call in a react component that looks like this.

```
login = () => {
   // <--- If I set the localStorage on this line the test passes.
   apiRequest.then(res => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
   });
}
```

To test it I have mocked the api call. I want to check that the local storage is called, so have also mocked localStorage, however, as the localStorage is set in the mocked api call it never gets called. My test code is below. Does anyone know how I can check that the local storage is set in a mocked call. I have confirmed that if I move the localStorage outside the apiRequest it works, so it is being mocked correctly, the issue is definitely that it is in the `apiRequest`.

```
// This mocks out the api call
jest.mock('./api', () => {
    return {
        apiRequest: jest.fn(
           () =>
             new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve();
             })
        ),
    };
});


const localStorageMock = (() => {
   const store = {};
   return {
      setItem: jest.fn((key, value) => {
          store[key] = value.toString();
      })
   }
})();

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
   value: localStorageMock
});

it('sets a token in local storage', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Login />);
    const loginButton = getByText(/login/i);
    // This passes
    expect(apiRequest).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    // This never gets called as it is being called in the apiRequest
    expect(localStorage.setItem).toBeCalledWith('token', '1234');
});
```

If anything is unclear let me know and I will provide more details.

Comment: actually `localStorage.setItem` is called in `render()` method that I believe is part of what `renderLogin()` renders rather `apiRequest` logic. so it's called. but since `localStorage.setItem` is called in async way you cannot check for it immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the response @skyboyer. How do you mean? I have updated the question which may have been after you posted. The update was *I have confirmed that if I move the localStorage outside the apiRequest it works, so it is being mocked correctly, the issue is definitely that it is in the apiRequest.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage.setItem` is called in async way through `.then`

```
login = () => {
   apiRequest.then(res => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
   });
}
```

So mocking has nothing to help with async flow. This small part

```
   .then(res => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
   }
```

is just put into the end of queue(it's named [microtask queue](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) if you are interested in details)

So your test code is finished and only after that this small microtask is executed.

How could you handle that? You can write test in [async way](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous) and put additional `expect` into dedicated microtask that will run after those with `localStorage.setItem` call.

You can use `setTimeout`(macrotask) for this:

```
it('sets a token in local storage', done => {
    const { getByText } = renderLogin();
    const loginButton = getByText(/login/i);
    expect(apiRequest).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    setTimeout(() => {
        // runs after then(....setItem) has been called
        expect(localStorage.setItem).toBeCalledWith('token');
        done();
    }, 0);
});
```

or create microtask with Promise/async/await:

```
it('sets a token in local storage', async () => {
    const { getByText } = renderLogin();
    const loginButton = getByText(/login/i);
    expect(apiRequest).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    await Promise.resolve(); // everything below goes into separate microtask
    expect(localStorage.setItem).toBeCalledWith('token');
});
```

[UPD] interesting thing about `await` that it can be used with everything else not only Promise. And it could work like `Promise.resolve(<some value here>)`. So in your case

```
it('sets a token in local storage', async () => {
    const { getByText } = renderLogin();
    const loginButton = getByText(/login/i);
    await expect(apiRequest).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(localStorage.setItem).toBeCalledWith('token');
});
```

will work as well. But I believe it looks confusing("waaaat? does `.toHaveBeenCalled()` return Promise for real?!") and suspicious(it's a magic! I'm not allowed to touch that!). So it's better to choose some version with straightforward "deferring"

Comment: thanks for this @skyboyer, it still doesnt pass though. Although when I remove the mock apiRequest it doesnt seem to work either, so I am unsure now if it is the mock or the async nature. It seems you are fairly certain it is due to async?

Comment: yep, it looks really straightforward issue for me. maybe I'm missing something. can you provide small but complete code snippet in codesandbox?

Comment: it took some time to make it work under old React without hooks(since codesandbox throws an error "jest is undefined"). at first in your tests you are checking for `'/sessions'` but actually calls `'/login'`. next your mock for api call returns `Promise.resolve()` but it should return object with `{data: {token: ... }}` otherwise it will throw error in `<Login>` because `response.data.token is undefined`

Comment: nope, still trying to resolve thing that `setItem` is not recognized as jest mock for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185031/discussion-between-skyboyer-and-peter-flanagan).

Answer (score 0):

A common problem when you try to test async code, is that you also need async tests, try to `await` to the `apiRequest` to be resolved and then verify if the local storage was called.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, but I don't think this is it, as the api call is mocked, it doesn't actually fire the real API call, but the one I defined in the snippet I provided in the question. I have just tried to add `async` and `await` and it was the same outcome.